# Hard Drive can only boot when selected manually in boot menu

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios

After I start the PC the BIOS tells me "no proper boot device found".
I have to select the hard drive manually in the boot menu, then everything works fine, the system boots properly, so I assume the hard drive works fine.

The hard drive is the first option in the boot order, I also tried disabling all other boot options like network or USB, still nothing.

The Mainboard is an Intel DQ57TM, I updated BIOS and Chipset, but it didn't help.
The OS is dual boot Win10 and Server 2012 R2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the boot order in the BIOS? There's usually three menu items like #1 boot device #2 boot device etc. Also, is the system time always correct when firing it up? Maybe the CMOS batter is dead

Comment: Boot order is right and system time seems ok. There are 9 other computers with the same configurations and components, they all manage to recognize their os.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it.**

I loaded the last known BIOS settings and redid everything in the boot section.
I still don't know where the error was, but now it's fixed.

Thanks for the help, though!